# Повторяющееся воспроизведение аудио

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы музыка играла на сайте, не переставая по кругу?

Comment: Под музыкой в данном случае понимается один файл или заранее сформированный плейлист?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя тэг `<audio />` HTML5:

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
  <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну здесь либо на фреймах создаёте страницы сайта, где в одном вы гуляете по своему сайту, а в другом плеер на flash играет.

Comment: А как это сделать со фреймом при условии что я умею создавать флеш